# No imprime los datos que le envió desde Ajax a Php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Disculpen quiera saber porque pasan los datos de mi Ajax a php cuando lo quiero guardar en una variable e imprimirlo. solo me aparece el valor de null, y en consola si me imprime cualquier options que seleccione.
Nose si me hace falta algún parámetro o función.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<form id="loginform" method="post">
    <select id="producto" name="producto" onchange="ShowSelected();">
        <option value="dias = 0">Mismo dia</option>
        <option value="dias between 1 and 2">1 a 2 dias</option>
        <option value="dias between 3 and 4">3 a 4 dias</option>
        <option value="dias >=5">Mas 5 dias</option>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
$prueba = "";
$datos = $_POST['cod'];
echo json_encode($datos);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowSelected() {
        /* Para obtener el valor */
        var cod = document.getElementById("producto").value;

        console.log('Value seleccionado correctamente');
              
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'prueba.php',
            data: cod,
            //pasas los valores de la variable datos
            success: function(data) {
                //si la peticion sale bien, aqui tendras los resultados que quieres
                console.log(cod);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //si la peticion falla aqui puedes saber alguna pista respecto al error 
                console.log(textStatus);
                alert('ALGO SALIO MAL, INTENTA DE NUEVO');
            },


        });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola, normalmente cuando se busca usar ajax es para tener elementos asíncronos, por lo que invocarse a si mismo pierde un poco el sentido. Sin embargo, si quieres ver que tu invocación funciona recuerda que los datos se envían en formato JSON de la siguiente forma: `data: {cod:cod}` y en la respuesta puedes sustituir el html del body de la siguiente forma `success: function(data) {$("body").html(data);}`

Comment: Ya lo hice como me comentaste y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basado en tu comentario, puedes simplificar el proceso invocando el submit del formulario al detectar el cambio. En este caso tu código podría ser:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<form id="loginform" method="post" action="prueba.php">
    <select id="cod" name="cod" onchange="ShowSelected();">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="dias = 0">Mismo dia</option>
        <option value="dias between 1 and 2">1 a 2 dias</option>
        <option value="dias between 3 and 4">3 a 4 dias</option>
        <option value="dias >=5">Mas 5 dias</option>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
$prueba = "";
$datos = isset($_POST['cod']) ? $_POST['cod'] : "";
echo json_encode($datos);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowSelected() {
        $('#loginform').submit();
    }
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

En donde desde el submit, recibes la variable post y hace la redirección al action del formulario

Comment: Muchas Gracias me sirvió mucho